# Telegram API - Отправка Emoji, созданных пользователем

Tags: telegram-bot, emoji

Каким образом отправлять смайлики из пака, созданного пользователем, через API Telegram?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению такое не получиться осушествить. Иначе какая суть telegrem premium